# openpyxl - TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, openpyxl

I need some help. Why I am getting this error?

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws_4.columns[12], 1):
    cellObj.value = "=(DAYS360($B${0},$Q${0}))-1".format(i)
```

I am getting the below error....

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws_4.columns[12], 1):
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What is `ws_4` and what is its `columns` attribute?

Comment: ws_4 is the worksheet and columns is the position of the column

Comment: @PrasannaK Welcome to StackOverflow [tour]. Please [edit] and add more information in  your question. For example, add the data you're using, the current and desired results.